# Can a raster map in GRASS be saved in JPEG/BMP format?

Tags: grass-gis, jpg

I'm trying to save a raster map in GRASS in jpeg/bmp format without using the GUI for d.out.file/d.save. Is there a script to do it? I tried r.out.gdal but it produced a map that is black and white.

Comment: What's the range of the map? If it has negative values, they cannot be represented in JPEG/BMP to my knowledge.

Comment: it is from -25 to 1000. I'll just fix the negative values and Try saving it again. I had generated a jpeg file from a raster map using r.out.gdal but it just produced a black and white map

Comment: If it is a floating point map, also that cannot be represented in JPEG or BMP format. What do you want to achieve with the export?

Comment: It is a floating point map and I am trying to save it in another image format rather than PNG since PNG cannot be embedded directly on the application that I am using.

Comment: E.g. GeoTIFF can stored floating point.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look on *d.out.file* command. See [that page](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass63/d.out.file.html) and format option. BMP is available.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GDAL library by:

```
r.out.gdal InRaster.dem format=JPEG output=out.jpg
```

have a look at the documentation [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.out.gdal.html).

Comment: Small note: From GRASS 6.4 onwards, the command name is r.out.gdal

Comment: Link only answers tend to become irrelevant with time.

Answer (score 1):

If for some odd reason d.out.file doesn't work, you could also add the GRASS raster to a QGIS map and use the File > Save as Image command. Alternatively, add to QGIS and create a layout which you can export as an image.